# Update de campo data no formato string

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Pessoal peguei um banco antigo de um cliente onde tem uma coluna de data de nascimento que esta no formato string e não date. Até ai tudo bem so que tem certas datas gravadas que não tem o 0 no mês ou no dia quando menores que 10. Preciso incluir o zero onde não tiver. Exemplo: Nascimento= 3/3/1980 preciso mudar para 03/03/1980 como eu faço isto no update? Obrigado

Comment: Você quer ajustar sob demanda? Ou você pode rodar algum processo específico uma vez só para ajustar em toda tabela?

Comment: @MurilloGoulart Eu posso rodar um processo para ajustar apenas uma vez. Cento assim ja ajusta toda a tabela e depois o novo sistema deles mantêm o restante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se houver um id (pode ser outro campo único para cada data)

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id,data FROM suatabela");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $id= $row['id'];
    $data= $row['data'];

    $partes = explode('/',$data);
    $dia=$partes[0];
    $mes=$partes[1];
    $ano=$partes[2];

    if (strlen($dia)==1){
        $update="true";
        $dia="0".$dia;
    }
    if (strlen($mes)==1){
        $update="true";
        $mes="0".$mes;
    }

    if ($update=="true"){
        $result=$dia."/".$mes."/".$ano;
        mysql_query("UPDATE suatabela SET data='$result' Where id='$id'"); 
    }
}
```

Obs: mysql está descontinuado

Comment: Amigo obrigado pela ajuda, mas eu preciso do código no MySQL para executar como uma query.

Answer (score -1):

Faz o ajuste de forma fixa, ou seja:

```
3/3/1980
```

Se o segundo caractere for "/", adiciona 0 no primeira posição;

```
03/3/1980
```

Se o terceiro caractere for "/" adiciona 0 na terceira posição;

```
03/03/1980
```

Comment: Sua resposta não condiz com a solicitação dele amigo.

Comment: @Douglas Pode exemplificar?

Comment: O que eu quis dizer é que pela pergunta dele ele pede um exemplo de como seria um update (um exemplo real). Você deu uma ideia de lógica pra ele e não é o que ele pede, entendeu ?